# how to compare numbers in cypress

Tags: javascript, numbers, compare, cypress, non-breaking-characters

I'm new to Cypress and I need to compare theese two numbers: 1045,92 and 1045,92

```
<div class="header-icon__text" data-pl-cart-in- 
total>1&nbsp;045,92&nbsp;р.</div>
<span>1 045,92 р.</span>
```

**I try like this**

```
 cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text1) => {
   
 cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text2) => {
      
 expect(text1).to.deep.equal(text2);
```

But:

```
AssertionError:
```

expected '1 045,92 р.' to deeply equal '1 045,92 р.'

**And I try like this:**

```
cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text1) => {
   
cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text2) => {

expect(Math.floor(text1)).to.deep.equal(Math.floor(text2));
```

`assert` expected `NaN` to deeply equal `NaN`

But:

I'm not sure that `NaN` is 1 045,92

Answer (score 4):

The part `&nbsp;` stands for non-breaking-space, it is used on a web page to stop a string with a space in the middle from breaking or splitting into two lines.

It can interfere with the comparison, as you found out.

This is how to clear it

```js
cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text1) => {
  cy.xpath("").invoke('text').then((text2) => {

    const val1 = text1.replace(/\s/g, ' ')   // clear both "&nbsp;"
    const val2 = text2.replace(/\s/g, ' ')   // making them ordinary space
    expect(val1).to.equal(val2); 
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```js
cy.xpath('selector1')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text1) => {
    cy.xpath('selector2')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text2) => {
        expect(text1.replace(/\D/g, '')).to.eq(text2.replace(/\D/g, ''))
      })
  })
```

`.replace(/\D/g, '')` will replace all non-Digit characters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This should do it. No need for a `deep.equal` here.
expect(text1).to.eq(text2);
```

I guess u pass these values as a string? But if you compare them string-like or number-like shouldn't matter, values should be identical.

And `NaN` is due to the `,` (and the space between 1 and 0) as this should be a `.`, like `1045.92`. `NaN` means `Not a Number` meaning your casting (`Math.floor()`) fails due to prior reasons.

Comment: I corrected my question

Comment: @Alex77 why don't you compare those 2 strings? this `p.` is not a number, so you got to strip that part away. where is that code though? it's not provided.